# When using appendChild, the justify property is invalid

Tags: javascript

At work, I need to delete the elements in a container and then add them back again. I found that the `text-align: justify` attribute is valid before I delete the elements, but invalid when I add the elements back in.

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <style>
    .container{
      width: 660px;
      text-align: justify;
      border: solid 1px #999;
    }
    .container:after{
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
    }
    .item{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      border: solid 1px red;
    }
    .itemImg{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="container">
      <a class="item" href="" > <img class="itemImg" src="https://uidesign.gbtcdn.com/GB/image/mobile/20190221_7802/ru400x240aa.jpg?impolicy=high" > </a>
      <a class="item" href="" > <img class="itemImg" src="https://uidesign.gbtcdn.com/GB/image/mobile/20190221_7802/ru400x240aa.jpg?impolicy=high" > </a>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
      const domParent = document.querySelector('#container');
      const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

      // save old elements
      const orderDomObj = [];
      const oldDoms = document.querySelectorAll('.item', domParent);
      oldDoms.forEach((item) => {
        orderDomObj.push(item)
      })
      // add new elements
      domParent.innerHTML = '';
      orderDomObj.forEach((value) => {
        fragment.appendChild(value);
      });
      domParent.appendChild(fragment)
    }

    window.onload = init

  </script>
</html>
```

I have found that in this section:

```
oldDoms.forEach((item) => {
    orderDomObj.push(item);
});
```

If I push the items into `orderDomObj` using template literals like so:

```
oldDoms.forEach((item) => {
     orderDomObj.push(`
         ${item}
     `);
});
```

Then the `text-align: justify;` CSS declaration works correctly.

Why does the template literal version work correctly, but the `push` version not work correctly?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to get text-align: justify to work?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking: how to get text-align: justify to work?

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Now that you have figured out a workaround, I think I know how it works.

The key portion is here:

```
orderDomObj.push(`
          ${item.outerHTML}  
        `)
```

You are using template literals in this section, and the newline character is creating a text node between the `<a>` tags. This mimics what is in the #container before you remove the elements, which you can verify in the console (this is your page without the JS running):

[image: Text Nodes]

So, in the original, you copy over the Element nodes, but not the text nodes in between them. Then, when you add everything back to the DOM, there are no text nodes between the elements, so the `justify` doesn't work.

You don't even need the document fragment, this script works just as well:

```
function init(){
  const domParent = document.querySelector('#container');

  // save old elements
  const orderDomObj = [];
  const oldDoms = document.querySelectorAll('.item', domParent);
  oldDoms.forEach((item) => {
    orderDomObj.push(item)
    orderDomObj.push(document.createTextNode('\n'));
  })
  // add new elements
  domParent.innerHTML = '';
  orderDomObj.forEach((value) => {
    domParent.appendChild(value);
  });
}
```

Here's a gif of editing the HTML to add in newline characters to mimic what's happening:[image: Demo]

But honestly, this does the same thing:

```
function init(){
  const domParent = document.querySelector('#container');
  const oldContainer = domParent.innerHTML;
  domParent.innerHTML = '';
  domParent.innerHTML = oldContainer;
}
```

I'm not sure why you are wiping the DOM then repopulating with the same content, but there seems to be many ways to go about that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In fact, it comes from a bug, and the above is just the extracted code. For some reason, I did not choose to modify the css.  But I still want to know why the js code `justify` attribute is invalid.

Comment: `the js code justify attribute is invalid` where in your js code are you using what you call a justify attribute? in your css, the `justify` is a css property value - so, no idea what your problem is at all

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrongly. It should be " But I still want to know why the  `justify` attribute is invalid."

Comment: Thank you very much for being so careful about this issue. The reason of 'wiping the DOM then repopulating with the same content' is that I just simulated the business code logic of the system, not the actual code.  see my answer,  `justify` does not work when there is no whitespace between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `init` function as follows, and it worked. But I still want to know why the code in the question did not work:

```
function init(){
  const domParent = document.querySelector('#container');
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  // save old elements
  const orderDomObj = [];
  const oldDoms = document.querySelectorAll('.item', domParent);
  oldDoms.forEach((item) => {
    // no
    // orderDomObj.push(item.outerHTML)
    // yes
    orderDomObj.push(`
      ${item.outerHTML}  
    `)
  })
  // add new elements
  domParent.innerHTML = '';
  orderDomObj.forEach((value) => {
    fragment.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(value));
  });
  domParent.appendChild(fragment)
}
```

I made some attempts and found that `justify` does not take effect when there is no whitespace between the elements. 
As shown in the following figure, element 1 and element 2 are abnormal, while element 3 and element 4 are normal.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V1DR.png)

code show as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
      </head>
      <style>
        .container{
          width: 660px;
          border: solid 1px #999;
          text-align: justify;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .container:after{
          content: '';
          display: inline-block;
          width: 100%;
          height: 0;
        }
        a{
          display: inline-block;
          width: 300px;
          height: 100px;
          border: solid 1px red;
        }
      </style>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <a> 1
          </a><a
          >2</a>
          <a>3</a>
          <a>4</a>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When using `appendchild` to add elements, there is no `whitespace` between the elements.

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the fact that reflow doesn't occur when you create a DocumentFragment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment.

Comment: Nevermind, see my other answer. It has to do with the text nodes that don't get copied over from the querySelectorAll() call.